# Are images in HTML-based timeline cards loaded from the url provided in the mirror api call?

Tags: google-mirror-api

Background:

- I set up a local server which exposes a web service that returns images.
- My Glass is connected to the same network as this server.
- In the timeline insert method, I am providing html which contains an img tag pointing to an image from that web service.
- The url contains a local network IP address (e.g. in 192.168.*)
- When I observe the timeline card on my glass I notice the image is not rendered
- However if I provide an image url for a public ip address, the image is rendered

Speculation:

- Images in timeline items rendered using HTML do not load from the provided url in the mirror api call.
- They could be loaded by GoogleImageProxy just like the default in gmail or through some other indirect method.
- Would love some confirmation on these, and if in the case of the GoogleImageProxy how could I turn it off?
- Gmail offers a way only for email to not render with it, no central site in Google to turn it off across all properties or any place in the MyGlass site.

Other Notes:

- I verified the image url is accessible on the local network by another device I tested with.
- The timeline: insert API reference: https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline/insert

Question:

- Are images in HTML-based timeline cards loaded from the url provided in the mirror api call?